# MS Access 2007 Insert Data in Database Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, gmail

Hello every one i have problem with ms access 2007 when i add 3 or 4 column then data don't insert when i make 2 column then data insert how solved the problem

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sqlconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim sqlquery As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim connString As String
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\My PC\Documents\Database16.accdb"
        sqlconn.ConnectionString = connString
        sqlquery.Connection = sqlconn
        sqlconn.Open()
        sqlquery.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (ID,Name) VALUES  (@ID,@Name)"
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TextBox1.Text)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox2.Text)

        'sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", TextBox3.Text)
        sqlquery.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlconn.Close()
        MsgBox("success")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Use [Parameters.Add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.add) instead of `.AddWithValue`, specifying the correct data type. Convert your data to the expected data type when needed.

Comment: What is @Number? Is there a column called number? What datatype is the column in the database? Is the ID column an auto-increment column? If you want to add an additional parameter you must adjust both the columns and the values in the Insert statement. Remember, in Access (OleDb), the order the parameters appear in the statement must match the order that they are added to the parameters collection.